# MessageDigest. Зачем полученные байты от digest() переводить в 16-ный формат?

Tags: java

Во всех примерах использования MessageDigest(), полученные байты хеша переводят в 16-ую форму, но зачем это делать? Если, допустим, для сравнения, то почему бы не сравнить байты полученного хеша?

```
static String GetHash(String fileName) throws IOException, 
                                              NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

    int nread = 0; 
    while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
      md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
    };
    byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

    //convert the byte to hex format
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
      sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    fis.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все верно, вы можете сравнивать байты.

Часто хеши хранятся в базе данных в виде строк, поэтому очень много примеров, которые переводят байты хеш-суммы в `hex`.

Comment: MessageDigest работает с байтами получается, и не затрагивает hex, да?

Comment: @MaksOhotnikov да

Comment: плюсики пока ставить не могу, большое спасибо:)

Comment: Еще часто хранят хеши в Base64